# How to insert datagridview rows to database if not exists, but if exists update then if every row have same id?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datagridview

I have datagridview in my project where I have columns productID, productname, quantity, price, discount and row price.

Insert is working fine:

```
private void addProducts()
    {
        string queryInvoice = @"INSERT INTO order_lines (orderID, productID, quantity, discount) VALUES (@orderID, @productID, @quantity, @discount)";

        /*
        string queryInvoice = @"IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM order_lines WHERE orderID = @orderID)
                                UPDATE order_lines
                                SET productID = @productID,
                                    quantity = @quantity,
                                    discount = @discount
                                ELSE
                                    INSERT INTO order_lines(orderID, productID, quantity, discount) VALUES (@orderID, @productID, @quantity, @discount);";

        */
        con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        try
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryInvoice, con))
            {
                con.Open();
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderID", InvoiceNumber);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productID", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ProductCode"].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["productQuantity"].Value));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@discount", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["productDiscount"].Value);

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                } // end loop
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Inserted!");
        }
    }
```

And it looks like this in database when inserted: [Database values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H66P2.png)

As you can see I tried also that if exists in database then update else insert, but it won't work. When it add first row, it updates then that row which have added and that reason I can see only one row (last one in datagridview) added in database.

I sent values to datagridview from other form:

```
private void productValues()
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(conString);
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ol.productID AS 'Tuotekoodi', p.name AS 'Nimike',ol.quantity AS 'Määrä', p.price AS 'á hinta', ol.discount AS 'Alennusprosentti', CAST(((p.price * ol.quantity) * (ol.discount/100)) AS decimal(16,2)) AS 'Total' FROM order_lines AS ol LEFT JOIN product AS p ON ol.productID = p.productID WHERE ol.orderID = @orderID", con);
            adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderID", dgv_invoices.CurrentRow.Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString());
            cmdbl = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
            dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            DataRow dataRow = dt.NewRow();
            dt.Rows.Add(dataRow);
            InvoicePage.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error\n" + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();          
        }
    }
```

But I have problems to update productid, quantity and discount..

So how I can fix that problem?

Comment: normally items have a uniqueID and then you can update using that ID anything/all that has changed

Comment: A DataAdapter will know which rows in a DataTable are new, changed or deleted.  All your code has to do is Update it

Comment: Any suggestions? I'm still new with this. First code is in form named InvoicePage, where I save values. And next code in InvoiceSelection form, where I send values to InvoicePage and to InvoicePage's datagridview.

Comment: So I added cmdbl = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter); to code. And then I use adapter.Update(dt).

Maybe I'm doing something right now. Now there is something wrong with query. Error is: "Dynamic SQL creation is not supported in many basic tables."